# CustomAdapter with SherlockListFragment

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I'm trying to implement custom rows for a SherlockListFragment by using SherlockFragmentActivity, SherlockListFragment, in conjunction with a CustomAdapter (*extends ArraAdapter*) I have 3 main layout files

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- This FrameLayout will be the PlaceHolder of the Fragments. -->
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**list_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:paddingLeft="8dp"
         android:paddingRight="8dp">
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#FF0000"
              android:text="No data"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and finally my rows

**list_row_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/list_row_button_fav"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/fav_star_icon">
    </Button>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_row_text_dist_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:text=".2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm getting an NullPointerException in my custom adapter at the getView method and I'm not sure why this is occurring? My getView pseudo-code is as below..

```
private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private final List<Model> myData;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Model> data){
        super(context, R.layout.list_layout, data);
        mContext = context;
        this.myData = data;
    }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;

            if(view == null){
                mInflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, parent, false);
            }
                // find button and text views by Id and set them accordingly, yadda, yadda...
               return view;
        }
```

stack trace:

```
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at com.app.test.MyListAdapter.getView(MyListAdapter.java:41)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1158)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-15 10:58:36.384: E/AndroidRuntime(16734):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: When you post code and say 'I'm getting an NullPointerException' its incredibly helpful if you actually post the Exception stack trace and then indicate which line is generating the npe.

Comment: sorry, will do. I don't want to litter the entire page with code, so i was trying to be conservative.

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.app.test.MyListAdapter.getView(MyListAdapter.java:41)`  What is line 41?

Comment: LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting a NullPointerException in `getView()` then this line looks like the culprit:

```
LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

I would guess that you forgot to initialize `mContext`... Also you only need one LayoutInflater so you can create `mInflater` in your Adapter's constructor.

Comment: Ok, where do you create your Adapter (`new MyListAdapter(...)`)?  The Context you pass here is probably null.

Comment: Strange. In my SherlockListFragment, i'm using getActivity() when I instantiate it. using

`MyListAdapter mAdapter = new MyListAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.id.empty, myList);`

Should I be using another method to get the Activity context?

Comment: Also to add, I do this in my `onActivityCreated` state of my SherlockListFragment where I create the Adapter and then use `setListAdapter(mAdapter)`

Comment: What happens if you call `getSherlockActivity()` instead?